# Flask test fails with 200 != <Response streamed [200 OK]>

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am currently writing a test that is supposed to test my Flask (actually connexion, which uses flask) API. In this test I have the following to statements:

```
response_add_subscription_1 = self.app.post(
            '/user/alice/data_source/{}/subscriptions/{}'.format(ds_uuid1, dp_uuid), content_type='application/json')

self.assertEqual(200, response_add_subscription_1._status_code, "Status code of response for subscription "
                                                                        "registration of alice is not 200!")
```

However, when running the test, it throws on the assert statement, saying:

```
AssertionError: 200 != <Response streamed [200 OK]>
```

When I change the assertion to

```
self.assertEqual('<Response streamed [200 OK]>', response_add_subscription_1._status_code, "Status code of response for subscription registration of alice is not 200!")
```

It still throws, but this time the AssertionError is the other way around:

```
AssertionError: '<Response streamed [200 OK]>' != 200
```

So it seems, my status code is `200` and `'<Response streamed [200 OK]>'` at the same time, but never what I assert. Can anyone give me a hint what I am doing wrong here? My assertion code works on other API resources...

Answer (score 0):

I was using content-type application/json even though I did not pass any json with the post request...